# What's the term describing regarding things/animals as humans?

Tags: single-word-requests

I believe there's a special word for it but I can't recall it. What would be a proper name for the phenomenon of regarding inanimate objects (or animals) as humans in terms of properties?

E.g. talking about a door that's been hurt or a chair that is sad. Alternatively speaking of dogs smiling or cows taking a coffee break with friends.

Comment: Anthropomorphism. Promoting animals, but demoting God (in our imaginations).

Comment: Or _personification_. Either can apply to non-animals, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[Anthropomorphism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anthropomorphism)* — n
the attribution of human form or behaviour to a deity, animal, etc

The verb, thanks to [@Bradd Szonye](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/42788/bradd-szonye) is *Anthropomorphize*

Comment: Also _anthropomorphization._

Answer (score 5):

I would say *personification*, but an answer has to be longer than that.

Comment: Yes, it *has* to be; it still isn't in essence. Lol.

Comment: +1 I'd argue that it's the content of an answer contra the question's intention that **has to** to proper. The very length doesn't, at least not in my view, as I can think of numerous **lengthy** answers that aren't good and quite many **short** that very well are. However, there's often some correlation between the size and the quality.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I can't parse or understand your first sentence. I was referring to the technical limitation on stackexchange whereby it won't accept an answer that is shorter than some number of characters.

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize that you had to add the extra characters to get the site to accept your contribution. I though that you meant that a reply **in general** needs to be more length in order to be regarded as acceptable. (Also, there's a typo - "*has to to proper*" instead of the correct "*has to **be** proper*").