# Is there a word that means a colour used metaphorically?

Tags: metaphors, colors

Examples:

Green to mean naive

Blue to mean depressed

Black to mean bad

White to mean good

In my googling of this question, I’ve come across a lot of philosophical and linguistic discussion about the phenomenon, but nobody seems to use a specific word to describe it.

The closest I got was **synaesthetic metaphors**:

> linguistic expressions in which a term belonging to a sensory domain
>   is extended to name a state or event belonging to a different
>   perceptual domain [[source](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/232926485_When_Color_Names_Are_Used_Metaphorically_The_Role_of_Linguistic_and_Chromatic_Information)]

I should point out that I don’t have a current use for such a word. I just started wondering about this today.

Comment: [**Colour symbolism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_symbolism) is a term I've come across before. It encompasses more than emotional mood though, if that was what you were after.

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here, but your question is not a duplicate of this one: [What's the term describing regarding things/animals as humans?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153857/whats-the-term-describing-regarding-things-animals-as-humans/153861#153861)

Comment: **Colour symbolism** seems apt. It’s a little broader than I wanted. I was hoping for a word that was restricted to language only, colour words, rather than including visual use of colours (e.g. red stop sign meaning danger).

Comment: @Mari-Lou Seeing this use of colour words as anthropomorphism is an interesting idea (and one I hadn’t considered - thanks!). It seems to fit for something like assigning the human emotion rage to red. But I’m wondering if it extends to assigning a moral value judgement to a colour, like black or white. Or assigning a political ideology to a colour, like red or green?

Comment: Well, aren't they justmetaphors? For instance the colour *blue* is quite interesting because it can mean so many things. If "I am blue" does that mean I'm sad, depressed, a conservative, or rude, e.g. *She turned the air blue*. I could also be blue with cold, but very often *blue* is also said to be calming, and of course when baby boys are born, they are kitted out with blue prams and clothes, so it's also considered a masculine colour.

Comment: And we’re back to the word metaphor :) Perhaps the term ‘colour metaphor’ is probably going to be the best, until everyone starts using chrometapahor – which I’ve just decided to coin. A portmanteau of ‘chromatic’ and ‘metaphor’. Hope it catches on.

Comment: "Blue" related: 1. [Why does swearing 'turn the air blue'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133271/why-does-swearing-turn-the-air-blue) 2. [Meaning and best case usage of 'Out of the blue'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28804/meaning-and-best-case-usage-of-out-of-the-blue/28805#28805) 3. [Why does one scream blue murder?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8875/why-does-one-scream-blue-murder?rq=1) 4. [What does “going blue” mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20207/what-does-going-blue-mean)

Comment: I don't think any of the users who posted their answers mentioned a term that is used to associate human emotions and features to a particular colour.

Comment: Blue is fascinating and probably the most varied example of chrometaphor (it’s catching on!). The association of a colour with a thing (blue for masculinity, red for danger) is a bit outside the definition I wanted and seems to be covered by the term ‘colour symbolism’ above. I’m wanting the definition to be restricted to the use of a colour word only, not including visual use of the colour.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see **synaesthetic metaphors** as the word you're looking for, because as in this example it is quite directly stating that pink is a gender:

> ‘Not just a colour’: Pink as a gender and sexuality marker in visual
>   communication

This is more like saying "**blue is depression**," not "**blue means depressed**." Assigning an emotion or giving a definition to a word isn't a metaphor.

You could use **[color assignment](http://www.joehallock.com/edu/COM498/associations.html)** (or color associations):

> Associations with color are defined, in part by Faber Birren (the
>   author of Color Psychology and Color Therapy) by our senses, language,
>   objects (or forms), and personality characteristics. color conveys
>   moods which attach themselves to human feelings and our psychic
>   make-up in an almost automatic fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I performed a variety of searches and found that it was "color metaphor" that was used in most cases. That is the phrase that I would use to describe this 'phenomenon'.

Comment: Some examples would greatly strengthen this answer.